# python 3: py2app "Modules not found (unconditional imports)"

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl, py2exe, py2app

I am building a standalone python3 app for a friend that has no knowledge about code whatsoever. For this app I use multiple modules including `tkinter` and `openpyxl`. I use `py2app` to make my app.

Even though the GUI part of the program works, the methods using the `openpyxl` module do not. As my terminal indicates:

```
Modules not found (unconditional imports):
 * StringIO.StringIO (pkg_resources._vendor.six)
 * _gdbm (dbm.gnu)
 * cjkwrap (texttable)
 * com (com.sun.jna)
 * com.jna (com.sun)
 * com.sun (com.sun.jna.platform)
 * copy_reg (pyexcel_io._compact)
 * defusedxml (openpyxl.xml.functions)
 * itertools.izip (ctypes.macholib.dyld)
 * itertools.izip_longest (ctypes.macholib.dyld)
 * lxml (openpyxl.conftest, openpyxl.xml.functions)
 * lxml.LXML_VERSION (lxml.etree)
 * lxml.etree.Element (openpyxl.conftest, openpyxl.xml)
 * lxml.etree.ElementTree (openpyxl.conftest, openpyxl.xml)
 * lxml.etree.LIBXML_VERSION (openpyxl.xml, openpyxl.xml.functions)
```

And so on ...

Now I first thought that my `setup.py` file was wrong, so I looked into that. Despite the confusion that I still have for the option `argv_emulation` I think it is correct.

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['foo.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': False,
           'includes': ['time', 'openpyxl', 'pyexcel', 'os', 'platform', 'tkinter']}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

The python code works, I have been testing it on a Mac VM, so there is no problem there.

I have noticed that this problem is not new and have found multiple threads treating it including:
- [Using py2app with tkinter and openpyxl and multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364295/using-py2app-with-tkinter-and-openpyxl-and-multiple-files) : but the .egg file only appears in `python 2.X` not in `python 3` so I don't know how to interpret it
- [Moving constants to a configuration file breaks py2exe and py2app](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/498) : this is exactly my problem, so I followed the [patch made for this in 08/2017](https://bitbucket.org/als/openpyxl/commits/aa3b82bd8fa3d795f09c1d8141bdbe6f76e800a8)
Unfortunately, the new openpyxl `__init__.py` file does not contain any links to .json files anymore.

So right now I'm at a loss. Any Ideas ?

*Edit : using the exact same code but with the `xlwings` module instead of the `openpyxl` module works perfectly. But the former opens the files to work in them. This is slow an (imo) not really pretty to work with.

Comment: py2app's messages 'Modules not found (unconditional imports):' seem to be mostly harmless. The problem may be somewhere else. You say 'Even though the GUI part of the program works, the methods using the openpyxl module do not.'
What exactly does not work? Do you get any error messages when running your program?