# cx_Freeze installing error: path not found

Tags: python, path, windows-10, cx-freeze

Questions:

**1.** When I try to install `cx_Freeze 5.1.1` in python or via cmd it says:

> error: [WinError 3] System can't find path: 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1\lib'

As you see it says `\\Windows\\v8.1` but I have `windows 10`. It seems to me that that's the problem, but how do i fix it?

**2.** I also downloaded `cx_Freeze.whl` and tried this in cmd:

> python -m pip install
>   C:\Users\Super\Downloads\cx_Freeze-5.1.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl

And it says:

> succesfully installed

I installed it but what would be the next step because it still doesn't work?

**Note, I have:**

Python 3.7 32bit

Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

cx_Freeze does not yet support Python 3.7, it has a bug. A bugfix exists but has not yet been released. See e.g. [What could be the reason for fatal python error:initfsencoding:unable to load the file system codec?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51183280/8516269), [cx_Freeze crashing Python 3.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51314105/8516269) and the issues [#395](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/pull/395) and [#407](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/407) on cx_Freeze's GitHub repository.

Try one of the following alternative solutions:

1. Install the latest (not yet released) version of cx_Freeze from the GitHub repository using

   ```
   pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze.git@master
   ```
2. Manually patch your current cx_Freeze installation as described e.g. in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54861853/8516269).
3. Roll-back to Python 3.6 if this is an option for you.